# Seg fault is eliminated when copying char** -- why is this?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
class uid
{

public:

    char id[6] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0'};

    uid() {}
    ~uid() {}

    inline void recursive(int x)
    {
        if(':' == id[x])
        {
            id[x] = '0';
            ++id[--x];
            recursive(x);
        }
    }

    char* operator++()
    {
        ++id[5];
        recursive(5);

        return id;
    }

    void write(char* pchar) const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            pchar[i] = id[i];
    }   
};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   

    const int MAX = 5000000;

    uid c;
    char** arr = new char*[MAX];

    //char** it = arr;

    //loop 1
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        arr[i] = new char[6];           

    cout << "allocated" << endl;


    //loop 2    
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        ++c;        
        c.write(arr[i]);
    }   

    cout << "data written" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) 
        delete[] arr[i];

    cout << "deleting arr" << endl;

    delete[] arr;   

    return 0;   
}
```

Running this will cause a seg fault in loop 2 when i == 999999 -- However, when adding the line:

```
char** it = arr;
```

The seg fault disappears -- does anyone have any ideas of why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Undefined behavior is by definition undefined. Anything can happen, including appearing to work.

Comment: If you can't find the undefined behaviour: What exactly happens on the one millionth call to the ++ operator?

Comment: @gnasher729, the index in `recursive` goes negative.

Comment: All you did when you added that line is that you moved the potential segmentation fault to another part of the program.  You didn't really eliminate it at all.

Comment: the one millionth call to the ++operator will change id[6] from {'9','9','9','9','9','9'} to {'0','0','0','0','0',0'} @gnasher729

Comment: @user3481813: And what does it also do?  Whenever `recursive()` creates a `'0'`, it also carries.  Where does the last carry go?

Comment: or so I thought it did...thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you go past 999,999 you are writing to memory not owned by `c`.  Declaring `it` changes the memory map enough that there is no immediate segfault, but the code is still not correct, and any other small change might bring back the fault.

Comment: doesn't the command: char** arr = new char*[5000000]; allow me to write to 0-4,999,999 ?

Comment: Your `MAX` is five million. It takes seven digits to represent numbers that big, but your `uid` structure and your inner `char` arrays have only six slots.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix it:

```
inline void recursive(int x)
{
    if(':' == id[x])
    {
        id[x] = '0';
        if (x) { // <-- added this
            ++id[--x];
            recursive(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now overflow will wrap around to `000000` instead of creating a 7 digit number in a space not big enough to hold it.